# RAML 1.0 - Securityschemes for custom schema

Tags: security, schema, raml

I need to include a security schema which was earlier used in RAML v0.8 as

> securitySchemes:
>     - highlysensitive: !include ./securitySchemas/http_api_sign_v1.91_dsig.raml 
>       securedBy: [highlysensitive]
>  mediaType: application/json*

but it is not working in RAML v1.0 .

How should i include a customer securityschema in RAML v1.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try without `-` before highlysensitive.

```
securitySchemes:
  highlysensitive: !include ./securitySchemas/http_api_sign_v1.91_dsig.raml 
securedBy: [highlysensitive]
mediaType: application/json*
```

source: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#applying-security-schemes